# Connecting to a MySQL DB with SnowFlake in a Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, mysql, jupyter-notebook, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, mysql-workbench

New to all of this.

I have a MySQL database, set up with a connection to Snowflake which allows me to query all of the data I have inside the MySql workbench. The connections looks like this

[image]

I am now trying to query the data inside a jupyter notebook (hosted locally), and tried using this code to connect, which is telling me theres an issue, and from the error message I am assuming this is due to the hostname. Can anyone clarify this?

```
conn=pymysql.connect(host='jdbc:snowflake://xy12345.location.snowflakecomputing.com/',
                     port=int(3306), 
                     user='myname',
                     passwd='thepasswordiuse',
                     db='TRAINING_DB')
```

Comment: Not sure why the port is mentioned there and also it seems to be incorrect. The value should be 443. Secondly, it should be "password" not "passwd".

Answer (score 0):

The account name itself is missing in front of the location, see here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-account-identifier.html

One example is `xy12345.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com/` and the xy12345-part is missing in your example.

Comment: I have that in, I just had it removed because I wasnt sure if it was unique to my company or not. Get the same error with it included.#

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'jdbc:snowflake://ug197421.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com/' ([Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed)")

Comment: You may remove the account name from your post since it is unique to your company, as you said. I was just interested in the Error number + description

Comment: I changed it to be not what it actually is so no worries, thanks for trying to help me out this is a very strange issue, I am the only person using python in my company so no one has made this connection successfully before, as such we have no documentation for the set up.